# ImportError: cannot import name get_path_info

Tags: django, heroku

My question is why foreman start not serving css file in dev environment ...? but my app running perfectly fine in heroku production server. Correct me if i am wrong, i thought `dj-static` is the only option for serving static in foreman env, so in order to work dj-static in wsgi.. follows...

```
wsgi.py 
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

if i am changing above code to

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "readtamil.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

then foreman start gives me this error

> ImportError: cannot import name get_path_info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `dj-static==0.0.6` in your requirements.txt file for Virtualenv. There might be a versioning issue on PyPI or a Django1.7 issue or the Heroku tutorial shows to use 0.0.5.

I've reported this issue to Heroku and their tutorial is now updated to reflect newer versions in the requirements.txt.